# Call a JDBC stored procedure with in and out parameter from nodejs

Tags: node.js, stored-procedures, jdbc

The problem is I can't have my out parameter in my procedure.
This is my error:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06577:output parameter not a bind variable
> This is my declaration procedure

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE "NAMEPROCEDURE" 
(
  P1 IN VARCHAR2,
  P2 IN VARCHAR2,
  P3 IN VARCHAR2,
  OutParametre out VARCHAR2  
)
```

code in node Js

```
var sforcesqldb = new JDBC(config);
sforcesqldb.initialize(function(err) {
  if (err) {
  console.log(err);
  }
});
sforcesqldb.reserve(function(err, connObj) {
  if (connObj) {
    console.log("Using connection: " + connObj.uuid);
    console.log("connexion établie");
    var conn = connObj.conn;
    conn.createStatement(function(err, statement) {
      statement.execute("call NAMEPROCEDURE('P1','P2','P4','OutParametre')", function(err, results) {
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log(results);
      });
    });               
 }});`
```

Comment: You probably need to use `prepareCall` instead of `createStatement`, and register the out parameter before you execute.

Comment: I do this but i have this error : conn.prepareQuery is not a function
   `conn.prepareQuery("begin  NAMEPROCEDURE(:in1,:in2,:in3,:out1); end;");
    conn.inputBind("in1","int1");
    conn.inputBind("in2","int2");
    conn.inputBind("in3","int3");
    conn.defineOutputBindString("out1");
    conn.executeQuery();
var out1=conn.getOutputBindString("out1");
   console.log(out1);`

Comment: I said [`prepareCall`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareCall(java.lang.String)), not `prepareQuery`.

Comment: With prepareCall , i have this error : return callback(new Error("INVALID ARGUMENTS"));
           ^

TypeError: callback is not a function

Comment: Sorry, I'm going from my knowledge of JDBC as accessible from Java; I can't help you further than this.